# Typesafe Config: Load configuration from src/test/resources

Tags: java, configuration, akka, typesafe, typesafe-stack

This is a beginner question. So my app structure looks like

```
src/main/java/...
src/main/resources/application.conf

src/test/java/...
src/test/resources/module/test.module.conf
```

**application.conf**

```
location: mainLocation
```

**test.module.conf**

```
location: testLocation
```

In my test, I do

```
  @Test
  public void testLoadConfig() {
    final Config config = ConfigFactory.parseResources("test.module.conf");
    System.out.println(config);
  }
```

and what I see

```
Config(SimpleConfigObject({}))
```

Surely something is not right, but I can't spot it

**UPDATE**

When I do just

```
  @Test
  public void testActorForFailure() {
//    final Config config = ConfigFactory.load("test.module.conf");
    final Config config = ConfigFactory.load();
    System.out.println(config.getString("location"));

  }
```

I see

```
mainLocation
```

So overriding is not working, why?

Comment: Try `System.out.println(config.getString("location"));`

Comment: `com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'location'`

Comment: You've misspelled the filename `test.module.config` instead of `test.module.conf`

Comment: What about "/module/test.module.conf"  to include package?

Comment: You can also add `ConfigParseOptions parseOptions = ConfigParseOptions.defaults().setAllowMissing(false);` 
and then do `ConfigFactory.parseResources("whatever.conf", parseOptions);`

which will throw an error if the resource is not found

Comment: @nuvio thanks!  This is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to load that test config file try this:

```
ConfigFactory.load("modules/test.module")
```

The base `ConfigFactory.load()` method looks to load 'application.conf'.  If you want it to load a different file you need to tell it what that different file is.

Answer (score 1):

To load from test-resource-root:

f.ex:

```
someModule/src/test/resources/some.conf
```

This works for me:

```
ConfigParseOptions options = ConfigParseOptions.defaults().setAllowMissing(false);
        
final Config config =  ConfigFactory.parseResources("some.conf", options);
```