# How to get property from application.property in Gatling

Tags: scala, gatling, scala-gatling

I'm trying to get some properties from an application.properties file in Gatling-Scala. I tried.

```
val properties: Config = ConfigFactory.load("application.properties")
val clientId: String = properties.getString("api.clientId")
```

I keep getting "com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing No configuration setting found for key 'api'". I put the application.properties file inside src/test/resources/application.properties and also in the root folder of the project.
I tried also to put the same information inside src/test/resources/gatling.conf as follows:

```
gatling {
  api {
    clientId = "..."
  }
}
```

But I get the error:

```
com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing No configuration setting found for key 'gatling'
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get the information in the gatling.conf file by installing the plugin HOCON  for .conf files and formatting it correctly.

Comment: Perhaps a comment (or better, an example) on how the formatting helped you, would likewise help others.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76104441/3052880) below:

> To load from test-resource-root:
>
> f.ex:
>
> ```
> someModule/src/test/resources/some.conf
> ```
>
> This works for me:
>
> ```
> ConfigParseOptions options = ConfigParseOptions.defaults().setAllowMissing(false);
>         
> final Config config =  ConfigFactory.parseResources("some.conf", options);
> ```

I applied this approach into my code for calling environment variables from my `gatling.conf` file. I used Kotlin language for my Simulation class.

Here is my code:

```kotlin
class TestSimulation : Simulation() {

    private val environment : String = System.getProperty("env")
    private val config: Config = ConfigFactory.parseResources("gatling.conf").getConfig("gatling")

    private val url = config.getConfig(environment).getString("url")
```

My `gatling.conf` file looks like below:

```
gatling {
  local {
    url: <your-localhost-url>
  }
  dev {
    url: <your-dev-env-url>
  }
```

Now, I am able to specify the environment with system properties using `gatling:test -Denv=local` in this command.